# Augury shows Change Detection Default eventhough ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush is configured

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have an Angular(4) component where I have activated ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush:

`tile.component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Tile } from './tile';

@Component({
    selector: 'tile',
    template: `
        <div>
        <div>{{this.data.title}}</div>
        <div>{{this.data.image}}</div>
    </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./tile.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class TileComponent {

    @Input() data: Tile;

    constructor() {}
}
```

`tile.ts`

```
import { List, Map } from 'immutable';

export class Tile {
  _data: Map<string, any>;

  get title() {
      return <string> this._data.get('title');
  }

  setTitle(value: string) {
      return new Tile(this._data.set('title', value));
  }

  get image() {
      return <string> this._data.get('image');
  }

  setImage(value: string) {
      return new Tile(this._data.set('image', value));
  }

  constructor(data: any = undefined) {
    data = data || { title: '', image: '' };
    this._data = Map<string, any>(data);
  }
}
```

But when I run it, Augury always shows me this component as having `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`:
[image]

No error is thrown.

Does anybody know why the ChangeDetectionStrategy would be reverted to Default, or if Augury may display the wrong value, how I could test if indeed ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush would be correctly configured?

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: put the following the in the constructor `setTimeout(()=>{this.data.setTitle('hello')}, 5000)`, is `hello` shown in `html` within 5 seconds?

Comment: @Maximus I get: ERROR TypeError: _this.data.setTitle is not a function

Comment: make sure `this.data` contains `Title` object, maybe put the code into `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @Maximus I've altered the code a little to:

    @Input() data: Tile = {'title': 'title', 'image': 'image'} as Tile;

    constructor() {

        setTimeout(()=>{
            this.data = {'title': 'hello', 'image': 'image'} as Tile;

            console.log("/// timeout executed");
        }, 5000);

    }

...and the title didn't change.

Comment: it means that change detection is indeed `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and Augury doesn't show it right. To see the difference, inject `constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef)` and apply it inside the timeout `cd.detectChanges()` - the view should be updated. Read more [here](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).

Comment: @Maximus Yes, seems to be a problem with Augury. Your explaination makes sense and I've tried it and it was exactly as you said. Do you want to create a proper answer to this post or how can I give you credit for it? :)

Comment: sure, posted the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple test you can use to check the current `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Add the following code:

```
@Input() data: Tile = {'title': 'title', 'image': 'image'} as Tile; 

constructor() { 
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
          this.data = {'title': 'hello', 'image': 'image'} as Tile; 
          console.log("/// timeout executed"); }, 5000); 
    }
```

If your view is updated in 5 seconds, you have `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`, if not, it's `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

You mentioned that the view wasn't updated, which means that the current strategy is `OnPush` and **Augury shows incorrect information**.

To see the changes, you can modify the example like this:

```
@Input() data: Tile = {'title': 'title', 'image': 'image'} as Tile; 

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
          this.data = {'title': 'hello', 'image': 'image'} as Tile; 
          console.log("/// timeout executed"); }, 5000); 
          this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
```